# Sacar variables de un servicio android

Tags: android, variables, servicio, mediaplayer

Hola comunidad de stackoverflow
Estoy haciendo una app que reproduce audio en streaming como servicio en segundo plano, lo que quiero es sacar variables del servicio desde el Activity así para actualizar los botones de play/pausa 
Este es mi código del service

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;

public class PlayRadio extends Service{
    private static final String LOGCAT = null;
    public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;


    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(LOGCAT, "Service Started!");
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    }

    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse("http://localhost:8080/hls/radio.m3u8"));
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d(LOGCAT, "Media Player started!");
        if(!mediaPlayer.isLooping()){
            Log.d(LOGCAT, "Problem in Playing Audio");
        }
        return 1;
    }

    public void onStop(){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }

    public boolean isPlaying(){

        if(mediaPlayer.isLooping()){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }


    }

    public void onPause(){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }

    public void onDestroy(){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent objIndent) {
        return null;
    }
```

Lo que quiero es desde el activity llamar a isPlaying() asi para saber si se esta reproduciendo o no el audio y actualizar los botones

EDITO

Asi es como llamo desde el Activity (dentro del event del boton)

```
if (!isPLAYING) {

                    isPLAYING = true;
                    Intent objIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayRadio.class);
                    startService(objIntent); 
               fab.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause); //Cambia el icono
                } else {
                    isPLAYING = false;
                    Intent objIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayRadio.class);
                    stopService(objIntent); 
               fab.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play); //Cambia el icono
                }
```

El boton cambia de icono de play a pusa y la música se reproduce tranquilamente
Al salir de la app esta sigue reproduciendo como un servicio en segundo plano, el problema esta en que al volver a entrar en la app el boton esta en "Play" y al darle click vuelve a lanzar el servicio que ya se estaba ejecutando, siendo que deberia de cerrarlo

Comment: Con un evento lo puedes hacer de manera muy sencilla, aquí te dejo un tutorial: http://www.androidcurso.com/index.php/recursos/tutoriales/50-arquitectura-y-diseno-avanzado-iu/unidad-2-diseno-personalizado-de-vistas/371-creacion-de-escuchadores-de-eventos. Estaría bien, además, que indicases lo que has intentado hasta ahora.

Comment: Ya tiene el boton, el problema esta en saber si se esta reproduciendo o no el audio

Comment: Desde el servicio, cuando empieza a reproducirse, se puede hacer un evento que ponga un booleano en la actividad a true y cuando se pause o pare la reproducción que lo pase a false. Así, desde tu actividad ya sabes si se está reproduciendo o no

Comment: Eso es lo que hago, pero cuando salgo de la app y vuelvo a entrar se restablece la variable

Comment: Entonces tu problema es como guardar una variable y que conserve su valor a la hora de cerrar la App. Puedes hacerlo con las Share preferences de Android o simplemente crea un fichero y guarda ahí su valor, así no se reiniciará al iniciar la app

Answer (score 1):

Si el Servicio puede ejecutarse en segundo plano seguramente lo inicias y detienes mediante un `Intent`:

```
Intent myService = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
startService(myService);
```

Por lo tanto no tienes una instancia para llamar el método isPlaying() que comentas; para determinar cuando cambiar el texto de los botones, deberá realizarse cuando detienes el servicio, cambias el texto de los botones y a partir del texto tu sabrías si esta activado o detenido, revisa este [ejemplo](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Music-in-Background).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Exactamente de esa forma es lo que hago, pero cuando salgo de la app y vuelvo a entrar el boton de esta en "play" siendo que la musica sigue reproduciéndose, ademas si ocurre un error de red la musica se detiene, asi que lo que yo necesito saber es si se esta reproduciendo o no el audio

Comment: Ahi lo edite y agregue como es desde el activity